# Dissimilar Metals In A High Heat Environment

Tags: materials, heat-transfer, stresses, steel

**Summary:**
Have two pieces of metal (7075 Aluminum & 4140 Steel) that appear to have fused together.

**Details:**
Machined a Flash Hider for a rifle.  Purpose was to direct all escaping gas forward, away from the shooter.  The machined tube is 7075 Aluminum.  The front cap was also 7075 Aluminum but gases were eating away at the cap.  Remade in 4140 Steel.  Front cap screws onto the aluminum tube.  1st test with the 4140 cap resulted in the cap now not being able to unscrew from the aluminum tube.

**Q1:** Was the temperature of the gases hot enough to fuse the two metals together?

**Q2:** Is there some electrolysis occurring that prevents these two metals from being used together in this type of application?

I can machine a new tube out of steel, but am trying to determine If this is actually necessary.  Thanks!

Comment: Aluminum is prone to galling . Coating with moly sulfide or graphite wiill give protection.

Comment: Thanks!  My bad.  I have Permatex Anti-Seize Lubricant that I have been using with the old aluminum front cap.  Just neglected to apply it this time................

So, if I had applied the compound, would I be OK with the different metals screed together in this instance?

Now, how to get the two pieces apart without damaging them?????????????????

Answer (score 1):

to enlarge slightly on Blacksmith37's answer: imagine a threaded joint between steel and aluminum, subject to axial shock loading. This would be like striking an aluminum nut screwed onto the end of a threaded steel rod with a hammer.

The striking action will cause the mating surfaces to scrub against each other slightly, which will break through the oxide layer on the aluminum and cause the newly exposed aluminum areas to quickly oxidize. Note that the assembly is not only hot, but exposed to corrosive gases which makes this oxidization much worse.

Worse still, there is a very vigorous chemical reaction which occurs between aluminum metal and iron oxide that liberates lots of heat called the *thermite process*. This process eats away at the iron oxide at the same time it forces more oxide to form, and the overall result will be the formation of a zone of mixed iron, iron oxide, aluminum, and aluminum oxide where the iron and the aluminum are in scrubbing contact. Trying to unscrew that joint will force the aluminum oxide (which is very hard) to act just like sandpaper in the joint, fouling the sliding surfaces and locking them so tightly together that the part will break before unscrewing.

Anti-sieze compounds poison the chemistry at the interface and also prevent the mating surfaces from being in clean contact with each other.